# Cut-Paste table from one worksheet to another with excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a weekly report that I am running. I have two separate worksheets. In the first worksheet I input my data (a table with 2 columns and unknown number of rows beforehand) and I want to create a macro where I click it and I cut all these data, and move them to the other worksheet. In the worksheet where the table is pasted, I want the data to be pasted as values ( include the initial formulas) and be pasted below the data from the previous week.

e.g. If I cut data from Worksheet1 from cells A1:B7, I want to paste the values in Worksheet2, in cells A7:B14. Next week, the data should be cut-pasted from cells A1:B5 in Worksheet1 to cells A15:B20 in Worksheet2

I have this code so far but I am doing something wrong. I am at a beginner level with vba.

```
Sub Movetabletototal()
Dim Count As Integer
Dim Table As Range
Dim CountRange As Range

Worksheets("TOTAL").Select
Set CountRange = Range("A2:A1000")


Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(CountRange) 
Worksheets("MIXER TOTAL").Select


Set Table = Range("P3:Q12")
Worksheets("TOTAL").Select
Worksheets("TOTAL").Range("A1").Select




ActiveCell.Offset(1, Count + 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Table
Worksheets("MIXER TOTAL").Select
Worksheets("MIXER TOTAL").Range("P3:Q12").Clear Contents

If Worksheets("TOTAL").Range("A2").Offset(1, Count) <> "" Then
  Worksheets("TOTAL").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Select
End If

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's `Table`? You don't mention that range in your post.  Where do you account for `A1:B7`?

Answer (score 0):

This code successfully does this:

> e.g. If I cut data from Worksheet1 from cells A1:B7, I want to paste
>   the values in Worksheet2, in cells A7:B14. Next week, the data should
>   be cut-pasted from cells A1:B5 in Worksheet1 to cells A15:B20 in
>   Worksheet2

Edit per your comment:

Using `P3:Q12` on "MIXER TOTAL" as your data that changes, and pasting to columns A:B on the "TOTAL" sheet after current data.

```
Sub Movetabletototal()
Dim Count As Integer
Dim copyRng As Range, pasteRng As Range
Dim totalWS As Worksheet, mixerWS As Worksheet

Set totalWS = Worksheets("TOTAL")
Set mixerWS = Worksheets("MIXER TOTAL")

Set copyRng = mixerWS.Range("P3:Q" & mixerWS.Cells(mixerWS.Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Row)

Dim newRow As Long
newRow = totalWS.Cells(totalWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If newRow > 1 Then newRow = newRow + 1

copyRng.Copy totalWS.Range(totalWS.Cells(newRow, 1), totalWS.Cells(newRow + copyRng.Rows.Count, copyRng.Columns.Count))

copyRng.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Change those ranges as necessary. (Note, currently if your data goes from P3:Q1000, it'll copy all that range. If you *strictly* want `P3:Q12`, then change `CopyRng` to just `mixerWS.Range("P3:Q12")`

[image]

Comment: @CMarneras - To keep the original data, just comment out (or remove) the line `copyRng.ClearContents`.